# Задержка между нажатиями клавиш в AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Вот мой макрос: `P:: Send, {t} {Up} {enter}`

Нужно, чтобы между нажатием `{t}` и `{Up}` была задержка в 200 милисекунд, но нахожу в интернете только как сделать задержку после выполнения всей строки, а мне нужно именно между нажатием клавиш.